# What's the difference between consumer and industrial grade strain gauge adhesive?

Tags: load-cell, strain-gage

Can I just use normal super glue and epoxy resin to attach a strain gauge?? What am I sacrificing by doing so?

Also, how are load cells so cheap and what kind of adhesive / covering do they use?

Comment: Shopping questions like this are usually closed; that's not really what this site is intended for. I can tell you though that super glue is probably not going to do what you want; it's very weak to shear stresses.

Comment: Look at the manufacturer, phidgets doesn't manufacture strain gauges, and find their recommendations. Or go to a manufacturer of strain gauges and start reading app notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search turned up phidgits own guide to using strain gauges.

https://www.phidgets.com/docs/Strain_Gauge_Primer

They recommend epoxy as a starting point. I was going to recommend JB weld, as I've had good luck with it, it's not conductive.

On a more general note, you can call adhesive manufacturers like Loctite, and they'll often be happy to recommend one of their adhesives. They have HUGE catalogs of different formulations, so it's likely they'll be able find something that will work for you. It'll probably come in a tiny tube and cost 15 bucks, but it won't be omega expensive. Plus they have bulk options if you need that.

Comment: wanted to circle back around and say you were absolutely right. we did order from Omega in the end, but it turns out that Omega's "SG496" was just a tube of Loctite 496. Definitely cheaper from Loctite!!

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a short decision help on selecting a good adhesive: https://www.hbm.com/en/4314/selecting-adhesives-for-strain-gauge-installation/

This is not only related to HBM products, but helps you with some decision criteria what to respect for a good strain gauge glue.